# how to bind the unique value for Domicile Name from json into the Dropdown in angularjs

Tags: angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

1. Array is this:

   $scope.domicile = {};
   $scope.domicile.users = [
         { DomicileName: 'European', PortFolioName: 'nternational Select x EM ADR', Alias: 'ADR x EM', Percentage: 1.0, Ticker: 'ADR', Category: 'ADRxEM', SortOrder: 1 },
         { DomicileName: 'European', PortFolioName: 'International Select x EM ORD', Alias: 'Ord x EM', Percentage: 4, Ticker: 'ORD', Category: 'ADRxEM', SortOrder: 1 },
         { DomicileName: 'European', PortFolioName: 'International Select with EM ADR', Alias: 'ADR w EM', Percentage: 4, Ticker: 'ADR', Category: 'ADRwEM', SortOrder: '' },
         { DomicileName: 'Developed Market Non-European', PortFolioName: 'International Select x EM ADR', Alias: 'ADR x EM', Percentage: 4, Ticker: 'ADR', Category: 'ADRxEM', SortOrder: 1 }
   ];

`enter code here`

Comment: Welcome to SO, please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help before asking question, this will help us to understand what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$scope.fetched = [];
angular.forEach($scope.domicile.users, function(value, key) {
    if (value["DomicileName"] === "European") {
        $scope.fetched.push($scope.domicile.users[key]); // add to array 
    }
})
```

Comment: sir could u tell me how to get only unique value for DomicileName to bind the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to push the data into `$scope.fetched = []` array, just write this in your code:

```
$scope.fetched = $scope.domicile.users.filter(function(user) {
    return user.DomicileName === 'European';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter data of **$scope.domicile.users** like this

```
$scope.domicile = $scope.domicile.users.filter(function(val) { 
    return val['DomicileName'] == 'European' 
});
console.log($scope.domicile);
```